# What Distribution Do I need?

Tags: probability, distributions, joint-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

Suppose I am drawing coloured balls from a bag.

The ball can be red, green or blue.

The probabilities of drawing a red, green or blue bag are uncertain, but I have confidence bounds for the probabilities.

I am 90% confident that the probability of drawing a red ball is 45%-55%. The tails are symmetric i.e. there is a 5% change that the probability is below 45%, and 5% chance that it is above 55%.

I am 90% confident that the probability of drawing a blue ball is 25%-35%. Again, the tails are symmetric.

From the above information, what can I infer about the probability of drawing a green ball?

I've had a read about the Dirichlet distribution, but it doesn't seem quite right for this. What else should I look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can explore the Dirichlet family of distributions to check if it contains some distribution satisfying your conditions. So, we have:

$$P\sim\text{Dir}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$$

It is reasonable to impose $\mathbb E(P)=(0.50, 0.30, 0.20)$, which implies gives us:
$$(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)=(0.5x,0.3x,0.2x)$$
For some positive number $x$. Now it only remains to find $x$. I have written the following R code to find what value of $x$ makes the central interval for $P_1$ have a length of $0.10$:

```
for (x in seq(1, 500, 0.001)){
  alpha = c(0.5,0.3,0.2)
  interval <- stats::qbeta(p = c(0.05, 0.95), shape1 = x*alpha[1], shape2 = x*(alpha[2]+alpha[3]))
  if(interval[2]-interval[1] < 0.10){
    print(x)
    print(interval)
    break
  }
}
```

This gives us $x\approx270$. If we write a similar code to assert the interval for $P_2$ has length $0.10$, we get a slightly different value of $x$:

```
for (x in seq(1, 500, 0.001)){
  alpha = c(0.5,0.3,0.2)
  interval <- stats::qbeta(p = c(0.05, 0.95), shape1 = x*alpha[1], shape2 = x*(alpha[2]+alpha[3]))
  if(interval[2]-interval[1] < 0.10){
    print(x)
    print(interval)
    break
  }
}
```

This gives us $x\approx226$. OK, so since the values of $x$ are different, the Dirichlet distribution does not allow your conditions to work exactly. But can we tweak it to make your conditions work with a good approximation? Let's try using $x=\frac{270+226}{2}=248$ and see what happens:

```
> x <- 248
> stats::qbeta(p = c(0.05, 0.95), shape1 = x*a[1], shape2 = x*(a[2]+a[3]))
[1] 0,4478658 0,5521342
> stats::qbeta(p = c(0.05, 0.95), shape1 = x*a[2], shape2 = x*(a[1]+a[3]))
[1] 0,2531545 0,3486831
> stats::qbeta(p = c(0.05, 0.95), shape1 = x*a[3], shape2 = x*(a[1]+a[2]))
[1] 0,1597154 0,2430401
```

OK, so $x=248$ gives us the distribution $\text{Dir}(124,74.4,49.6)$, which gives us $90\%$ intervals $(44.7\%-55.2\%)$ for $P_1$, $(25.3\%,34.9\%)$ for $P_2$ and $(16.0\%,24.3\%)$ for $P_3$.

**TL;DR**

- The Dirichlet distribution is a good choice for the problem at hand
- The adequate set of parameters is something close to $\alpha=(124,74.4,49.6)$
- The probability of drawing a green ball is $\mathbb E[P_3]=0.20$ (this part follows from the other probabilities being $50\%$ and $20\%$, in average) and a $90\%$ interval around it is $16.0\%,24.3\%$ (AFAIK this part depends on using the Dirichlet distribution)

Comment: Nicely written and very well explained. Thank you @PedroSebe.

Answer (score 1):

If we call the probabilities as $P,Q,R$ for green, red and blue respectively, and assume the marginals given are correct, we can do the following w/o assuming anything about the joint PDF (i.e. Dirichlet or not):

$$P(\text{Green})=\int_{0}^1 P(\text{Green}|P=p)f_P(p)dp=\int_0^1 pf_P(p)dp=\mathbb E[P]$$

So, it is the expected value of $P$. If the marginal is symmetric around $50\%$, assuming the mean is defined, probability of drawing a green ball from the urn will be $0.5$.